# Azure Pipelines - How to list Commits and Work Items by Application/Folder using a git mono repo strategy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, monorepo

I recently migrated to a git monorepo strategy where I keep all my APIs and applications, I'm also following trunk-based development using Azure DevOps.

Since each application lives on its own folder in the root of the git repo, I was able to enable branch policies and PR requirements driven by that folder. For example, request PR reviews from the Mobile team to every PR that modifies anything inside the MobileApp/ folder.

Likewise, I was able to configure build and release pipelines to deploy the correct application only when there are changes to its folder to every environment.

Now, I'm having an issue when deploying to environments that require approval. Previously, I was able to use the Commits and Work Items summary in the approval stage, to know exactly what are the work items that the release is pushing to production but because now every application lives in the same repository, I'm getting a report with all the commits since the previous pre-prod release, regardless the application:

[image]

Only the first commit modifies any files inside the MobileApp/ folder. The other 4 commits belong to different applications and teams.

Is it possible to only show the commits/work items filtering by the folder? For example, the same way Azure Repos work if we select a folder and click to see the history:
[image]

If not, can you think of any way to get this information while taking a mono repo approach?

Comment: I've opened a new suggestion for this feature on VS community.  Please vote on it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Account-for-monorepos-in-work-and-commit/1498992?space=21&entry=myfeedback

Answer (score 2):

Related feedback:

- Q: Will you let us manually pick or attach related work items to a pipeline or Release?

  - A: No - Closed.
  - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-Related-work-items-to-BuildsRelease/740058?space=21
  - Sep 19, 2019
- Q: It is a bug you don't support path filter, like build trigger, when associating commits to a build/release.

  - A: Not a bug - Closed.
  - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-pipelines-related-work-items-not-considering/1063605
  - Jun 03, 2020
- Q: Will you add a new feature to support path filters, so monorepo pipelines don't list all commits to all folders per build/release?

  - A: Ignored, now closed automatically because of age.
  - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Releases:-Add-a-path-filter-featur/1015157?space=21
  - May 01, 2020
- Q: Support same path filter as triggers to filter commits. Filed by MSFT employee (as a suggestion, converted from earlier bug)

  - A: Ignored, now closed automatically because of age.
  - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/related-work-items-not-considering-path-filter-in/1076618
  - Jun 12, 2020

Conclusion: Pipeline team has ignored or closed this many times.  Looks like this feature is not going to happen.  But if you can benefit from this feature I hope you'll vote up this answer.  I've marked it "Community wiki", please add any new related feedback items you find.

Comment: It is sad so many Azure Devops features don't work together.  They have such investment into build/deploy pipeline YAML to enable monorepo scenarios.  But when it comes to approving those deployments the person approving is spammed with all all commits, can contain tons of unrelated stuff the approver has to wade through with no way to filter the commit or associated work items.  If you won't auto-filter at least let us manually prune or manually associate what work is related to what build or release.

Comment: Reported Jul 20, 2020 - 
Account for monorepos in work and commit linking to pipelines
https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Account-for-monorepos-in-work-and-commit/1119652?space=21&entry=suggestion

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to only show the commits/work items filtering by the
>   folder? For example, the same way Azure Repos work if we select a
>   folder and click to see the history:

Are you trying to `get a path filter` or something similar to that in `Release=>Stage log=>Commits` page? If so, I'm afraid there's no such out-of-box feature available for now.

To check Commits related to changes in specific folder, you can navigate to Azure Repos Files page to check the history. As for workItems related to the commits, you can find that in Commit=>Details:

[image]

But if you do want a `path filter` feature in stage-related commits and workitems(in your first page) to be added, try submitting a feature request in our [user voice forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). The team there would check your idea and consider about that. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I just added the request. One question I have though, Microsoft (and other big companies) claim they use monorepos to several of its projects. 

How do you guys keep track of what changes go into each release when you have several applications with possibly different releases cadence in the same repository?

Comment: Sorry but it's a different issue from the original one. Maybe you can post a new issue about the question.

Comment: It's not different. That's the intend of my question and I ended the question asking if anyone could provide a way to track that information if it's not supported by Azure DevOps.